# MySQL time difference in consecutive rows with hierarchical data

Tags: mysql

How does one query the time difference between consecutive rows with a hierarchical data? For example, I'd like to go from the following table:

```
+-------+----------+---------------------+
| group_id |  event   |     event_time      |
+-------+----------+---------------------+
|     1 | alarm    | 2016-12-01 17:53:12 |
|     1 | alarm    | 2016-12-01 17:59:43 |
|     2 | purchase | 2016-11-29 09:49:47 |
|     2 | purchase | 2016-11-29 09:53:51 |
|     2 | purchase | 2016-11-29 09:57:59 |
|     2 | alarm    | 2016-11-29 10:01:02 |
|     2 | alarm    | 2016-11-29 10:13:27 |
|     2 | purchase | 2016-11-29 10:15:00 |
|     2 | purchase | 2016-11-29 10:16:24 |
+-------+----------+---------------------+
```

to:

```
+-------+----------+---------------------+------------+
| group_id |  event   |     event_time      | time_delta |
+-------+----------+---------------------+------------+
|     1 | alarm    | 2016-12-01 17:53:12 | 0          |
|     1 | alarm    | 2016-12-01 17:59:43 | 00:06:31   |
|     2 | purchase | 2016-11-29 09:49:47 | 0          |
|     2 | purchase | 2016-11-29 09:53:51 | 00:04:04   |
|     2 | purchase | 2016-11-29 09:57:59 | 00:04:08   |
|     2 | alarm    | 2016-11-29 10:01:02 | 0          |
|     2 | alarm    | 2016-11-29 10:13:27 | 00:12:25   |
|     2 | purchase | 2016-11-29 10:15:00 | 0          |
|     2 | purchase | 2016-11-29 10:16:24 | 00:01:24   |
+-------+----------+---------------------+------------+
```

Data above is illustrative; my data actually has many groups and many events. So basically, I'd like calculate the time difference whenever the group_id and the event is the same in consecutive rows.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: there are 5 purchase items how do you know which pair to compare??

Comment: `00:02:08` should be `00:04:08`

Comment: @e4c5 I think it's ordered by `event_time`.

Comment: It's ordered by group_id, event_time.  I've looked into using lag and partition by, but not quite getting the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the previous time for a given group by doing:

```
select t.*,
       (select t2.time_delta
        from t t2
        where t2.group_id = t.group_id and
              t2.event = t.event and
              t2.event_time < t.event_time
        order by t2.event_time desc
        limit 1
       ) as prev_event_time
from t;
```

You can then get the time difference in a variety of ways, such as:

```
select t.*, timediff(event_time, prev_event_time)
from (select t.*,
             (select t2.time_delta
              from t t2
              where t2.group_id = t.group_id and
                    t2.event = t.event and
                    t2.event_time < t.event_time
              order by t2.event_time desc
              limit 1
             ) as prev_event_time
      from t
     ) t
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using user defined variables:

```
SELECT 
    group_id, event, event_time, diff time_delta
FROM
    (SELECT 
        t1.*,
            CASE
                WHEN @event = event AND @group = group_id THEN TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(event_time, @et), '%H:%i:%s')
                ELSE 0
            END diff,
            @event:=event,
            @group:=group_id,
            @et:=event_time
    FROM
        (SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        your_table
    ORDER BY group_id , event_time) t1
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @event:='', @group:=- 1, @et:='') t2) t;
```

`@et` variable stores the previous event_time within each group of group_id and event.